# Is there a way of listening to when an Installation prompt open up on Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I've been trying to develop and application for rooted devices and I want to trigger an action when an Apk is about to be installed ( when the PackageManager Activity is launched asking the user to start the installation).  I have been trying to use the following intent filter but it does not seem to work.

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL);
intentFilter.addDataScheme("package");
registerReceiver(br, intentFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<receiver
android:name="com.your.receiver"
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
                <data android:scheme="package"/> 
            </intent-filter>
```

Works on most rooted devices

Apart from this i used some adb helper class which were of some help by getting info from logcat

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! My problem is a little bit different. The PACKAGE_ADDED action only is broadcasted after the installation finishes. But I'm looking for the instant when the PackageManager Installation Popup shows up, that is, before installation.

Comment: i dont think so because if an app is a system app then atleast on rooted device user can perform silent install too that dosent even show any prompt

Comment: Nevertheless i will look into it and let you know